# g++ 4.6 bug with stringstream?

Tags: gcc, g++, iostream, stringstream

I have used stringstream as pipes within a single thread in the past (with g++ 4.5) with no problem. Now I tried the same approach, but I can't get it to work in g++ 4.6: the problem is that the internal `streambuf` is never filled beyond the first byte.

Consider this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        stringstream pipe(ios_base::in|ios_base::out|ios_base::binary);
        const char* in="lol";
        pipe.write(in, 4);
        char out[4]={0};
        cout<<pipe.readsome(out, 4)<<" "<<out<<endl;
}
```

This prints unexpectedly "1 l".

Is there any evident error in my usage of stringstream? Otherwise, I must conclude that there's some flaw in g++ 4.6 STL.

P.S.
I have the same results using a iostream with an associated stringbuf, which is basically what stringstream does.

Comment: It looks like `readsome` reads only one byte, which, as far as I understand, is correct behavior. If you want to read exactly 4 bytes use `read`.

Comment: yes, but the fact is that this code worked with g++ 4.5, because the in_avail() method of the streambuf object returned the correct amount of bytes (4). Now, it returns *always* 1, so readsome() reads only 1 byte, even if it could read 4. In my application, I have to know in advance how many bytes I can read.

Comment: I'm using GCC 4.4.5, and `in_avail` returns 1 for me as well. So if it's a bug, then it's quite old. I don't have access to 4.5 of gcc, so can't test that right now.

Comment: It looks like they changed the implementation in 4.6. But, it's still correct. `readsome` reads up to n characters. There is no guarantee that it will read more than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-read the specs, and at last I decided to use this piece of code to retrieve the available bytes in the stringstream pipe: `pipe.tellp()-pipe.tellg()`.
As far as I know, it's compliant to everything, and so it's assured to work always.